# Custom og:type not appearing in Facebook object debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am defining a custom og:type. For example "watchevent:event". 
In the html page containing this "event" object i have defined meta tag, 
 meta property="og:type" content="watchevent:event"

But once i debug this html page using Facebook object debugger it is showing the og:type property as "article".

Why is the custom og:type not shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have a caching issue?

Try adding a "refresh" parameter in [the debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug):

http://www.yourdomain.com?fbrefresh=AnyString